How can I test Turtle library functions with pytest?
Long story short: I'm a middle school computer science teacher who has recently completely lost a program I used to teach Python syntax. I'm trying to rebuild it myself using pytest. My background isn't in Python, but Java, JavaScript, and C#, but the district I work for is insisting on Python. So I'm teaching myself the syntax as well as teaching my students. (It helps that I have the foundations of code so I can learn faster than them!)
I'm trying to figure out how to test to see if my students have completed the Turtle code correctly.
So if I ask a student to draw a dotted line with Turtle and they instead draw a solid line, how can I test this? Logically, it should be possible to have pytest check code instead of output, right?
The code should be (and yes, this is the precursor to using it in a loop):
def dotted_line():
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(5)
  t.penup()
  t.forward(5)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(5)

There has to be a way to test this, right? Or can I convert the code to an output in the test?

In the test, provide your own "substitute" object t that the method will use. That object should have the same interface as the "real" t. Run the method and let the substitute t record what was done to it. Then the test checks if t is in the correct state.

@MatBailie How do we do that? Because this isn't OOP they're doing, it's much simpler. The t object is called in main.py and used throughout the document. It's been working so far the way I've done it.

You need to show this in the question (don't describe it, show it). Edit the question to include a [mre] of the python script you're trying to test.

@MatBailie Nevermind, I'm just cutting it. I'll teach Turtle manually.

This is a good question. The problem with turtle is that the output is a graphics window rather than text or an object you'd typically test. There are many (infinite) ways to write code that produces the image on the screen, so any test case that mocks the turtle object and ensures certain methods were called with certain values is a non-starter.
With that context in mind, I would write a test suite that runs the student's turtle code and captures the output in an image file. From there, it's a matter of setting up a visual diff using a library like Pillow's ImageChops, which can help ensure slight variations aren't problematic. You can say something like: if the student's image is within 100 pixels of the expected result, pass, otherwise fail--or even do partial grading based on the accuracy.
The downside of this approach is that instrumenting the code to produce the file is a little bit tricky to do automatically after the assignments have been turned in. Students would probably have to be given the image generation code as a harness.
Also, if the student's output is basically perfect, but shifted by a few pixels such that it throws the dotted line off center with respect to the reference image, it'll produce a failure. Providing the harness to students so they can run their own code and adjust is a good way to avoid surprises and unfairness claims.
Another cool aspect of this is that many image diffing libraries show the diff as an image, so you can give that diff image to students so they can see exactly why they failed, rather than a vague "image didn't match expected" report.
Another variant on this approach is to capture a full window screenshot using any programmatic tool you like, then proceed with diffing. This avoids having to modify the Python code to get the image written.
You could even use a library like PyAutoGUI to interact with the turtle program, then take snapshots along the way. That's pretty advanced though.
